# How to add a constant uneditable text at the end of editText android?

Tags: android, email, android-edittext, textview

I am trying to implement a sign up screen, where I have two `ediTexts` inside two `TextInputLayouts` (one for email and one for password). However, for email, I want to have a constant text for the domain. Is there any way I could set the text to remain at the end of the editText or any better suggestion? Email here is the hint, I want the user to be able to type at the start only, with the *@example.com* remaining constant.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can either try one of these:

1) In a horizontal LinearLayout, put your textInputLayout (width=wrap_content) and a textView (width=0dp & weight=1) containing the domain name. Whenever the email edittext receives focus, show the textview else hide it.

2) Add a text watcher to the edittext and onAfterTextChanged method add the domain name to the string. Here you have to check whether the edittext's string ends with the domain name or not... if not then only add the domain name else do not add it. Personally, this is not an elegant solution as cursor wont be at expected position after text changes.

Thanks

Comment: okay thanks i will try your first suggestion soon. As for the second, I limit the amount of characters in the ditText to the number of characters of the email before the domain since I already know that (5 in my case), do you think that would make it easier to use textWatcher?

Comment: Well, if you set the limit on number of characters in editText to 5. Then do you think your domain name will be visible in it??

Comment: The limit is on the inserted text from the user, i.e i only allow him to type 5 characters. Isn't related to visibilty

Comment: If you set maxLength to 5, then user can type only 5 characters. But, if you append any more characters to it programmatically, then also only 5 will be visible.

Comment: Okay i see what you mean, I will try the first option then, thank you

Answer (score 0):

So here's the updated solution.

```
    emailEditText.setText("@gmail.com");
    emailEditText.setSelection(0);
    emailEditText.requestFocus();
    emailEditText.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
        {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                    Layout layout = ((EditText) v).getLayout();
                    float x = event.getX() + emailEditText.getScrollX();
                    offset = layout.getOffsetForHorizontal(0, x);
                    maxOffset = emailEditText.getText().toString().indexOf("@");

                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                    if(offset > maxOffset && maxOffset >= 0) {

                        emailEditText.setSelection(maxOffset);
                    }
                    else if (offset >= 0) {
                        emailEditText.setSelection(offset);
                    }

                    event.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL);

                    showSoftKeyBoard(emailEditText);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    public void showSoftKeyBoard(View focusedView) {
    if(getCurrentFocus() != null) {
        ((InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE))
                .showSoftInput(focusedView, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
    }
}
```

Finally a Disclaimer... you can move around the cursor but there is no holder that you usually see at the bottom of the cursor.

Comment: I have researched, but I haven't been able to keep the text at the end.

Comment: @riadrifai My bad! I misread your question and I will update my answer in some time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library ,i have worked

https://github.com/gotokatsuya/ParkedTextView